# Swift ios unit test mock API

Tags: ios, swift, api, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to have this API provider unit test. but i fail to cover this kind of API.

I have tried, the mock function is called, but it does not count the unit test coverage which line is still not passing (in red color)

```
class APIProviderTest {
  func test_API {
     sut = MockAPIProvider()
     let promise = sut.sendEmailVerificationApi(userEmail: "12312")
        XCTAssertAfterPromiseSuccess(promise: promise, assertActions: {
            response in
            XCTAssertTrue(response)
        })
   }
}
```

```
class MockAPIProvider: APIProvider {
 var isFuncCalled = false
 func sendEmailCodeApi(userEmail: String) -> Promise<Bool> {
    isFuncCalled = true
 }
}
```

```
Class APIProvider {
   func sendEmailCodeApi(userEmail: String) -> Promise<Bool> {
       return getToken.execute()
           .compactMap { $0.accessToken }
           .then { [self]
               accessToken -> Promise<Bool> in
               return sendEmailVerificationCode.execute(
                   token: accessToken,
                   userEmail: userEmail
               ).then {
                   res -> Promise<Bool> in
                   res == "success" ? .value(true) : .value(false)
               }
           }
           .recover { _ -> Promise<Bool> in
               return .value(false)
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems you're not testing `APIProvider`, you're testing your mock `MockAPIProvider`.

Comment: yes.... how to test the APIProvider..

Comment: You don't need to create a mock for the thing that you're gonna testing, it doesn't make sense. You just instantiate the class, call methods of the object and assert desired outcomes. If you're not good with unit testing concepts in general, I suggest reading some manual, there are plenty of them. Here's one: https://www.raywenderlich.com/21020457-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial